# Maven release plugin version 2.5.3

Tags: maven

When I use a command mvn release:prepare it will shows the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project MR-1: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: 'C:\Program Files\Git\https;\\github.com\Nivedha18-V\Maven-Release.git' does not appear to be a git repository
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Could you post output of git remote -v command executed in your git project dir?

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: No,I didn't use git remote -v command @Martin

Answer (score 0):

Here I Attach my pom.xml

If need any changes in this file please notify me.

```
<groupId>org.MavenRelease1</groupId>
  <artifactId>MR-1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MR-1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <scm>
     <connection>scm:git:file:///https://github.com/Nivedha18-V/Maven-Release.git</connection>
     <url>scm:git:file:///https://github.com/Nivedha18-V/Maven-Release.git</url>
    <tag>MR-1-0.0.1</tag>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
     <repository>
        <id>Maven-Release</id>
        <url>https://github.com/Nivedha18-V/Maven-Release.git</url>
     </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.3</version>
         <configuration>
            <goals>release</goals>
         </configuration></plugin></plugins></build>
```